# Problems with HTTPS communications for RESTful client/server

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https

I am attempting to set up web-based security via HTTPS on an application I've written that uses Spring Boot to provide RESTful capabilities. The application works as expected using just HTTP.

I have done a fair amount of research into what I need to do to "enable" HTTPS in the application (at least I think so) and will provide snippets of code and configuration to illustrate what I have.

I think that I'm close, but it's not working yet and the various things I tried have yielded no success.

The current implementation does not require that a service (server) verify the credentials of the client. Also, I am not requiring any form of "user" authentication.

Here is a brief description of the current set up:

- A "mission planner" service, which will make REST calls to two other
  services to perform some work.
- A "route generator" service, which when called by the mission planner, will return some data for a response.
- A "route assessor" service, which when called by the mission planner, will return some data for a response.
- A "client"
  that will make a REST call to the mission planner to "plan a mission". The mission planner returns nothing.

There is also a "dummy" service that simply returns the current time to a GET request from the client. The simple tester.

All five of these elements are implemented as `@Service`s and the mission planner, "route" services and dummy have corresponding controllers (`@RestController`) where the REST endpoints are mapped.

I have certificates generated for the three services (mission planner and the two "route" services - the dummy just uses one of the "route" certs) and these files are located in a "keystore" location. I also have a "truststore" location that contains the public key of the generating CA. All five services have the truststore.

I cannot get the client to talk to any service (using "dummy" for simplicity). I have also tried to access the dummy endpoint through a web browser and the results would seem to indicate that some portion of the communication pipeline is occuring, but failing.

Below are snippets of the code, to hopefully show the picture, code-wise.

**SERVER** ("dummy" as the example)

Dummy.java:

```
@Service
@Profile("dummy")
public class Dummy {
  public String doIt() {
    return Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}
```

DummyController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rst")
@Profile("dummy")
public class DummyController {
  @Autowired
  private Dummy service;

  @GetMapping(value = "/dummy", produces = "text/plain")
  public String dummy() {
    return service.doIt();
  }
}
```

**Note**: The classes below and the properties in application.yml are what I adapted from an example found on the web ( https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-tls-example ). I do not quite understand the concept of a "role" that has been defined. There is much here that I still do not understand.

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityAuthProperties.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final Logger                 logger = LogManager.getLogger();
  private final SecurityAuthProperties properties;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfiguration(SecurityAuthProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    // properties.getUsers().forEach((key, value) -> {
    // try {
    // auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    // .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder())
    // .withUser(value.getId()).password(value.getPassword()).roles(value.getRoles());
    // logger.info("Added user " + value.getId() + " with password " + value.getPassword());
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // throw new SecurityConfigurationException(
    // "Problem encountered while setting up authentication mananger", e);
    // }
    // });
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    properties.getEndpoints().forEach((key, value) -> {
      try {
        for (HttpMethod method : value.getMethods()) {
          // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(method, value.getPath())
          // .hasAnyAuthority(value.getRoles()).and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(method, value.getPath()).permitAll().and()
              .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
          logger.info("Added security for path " + value.getPath() + " and method " + method);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SecurityConfigurationException(
            "Problem encountered while setting up endpoint restrictions", e);
      }
    });

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    // TODO - what (if anything) do we do here?
  }
}
```

SecurityAuthProperties.java:
(The "users" portion currently disbaled as we are not using it.)

```
@ConfigurationProperties("security.auth")
public class SecurityAuthProperties {

  private static final String   ROLE_PREFIX    = "ROLE_";
  public static final String    ROLE_ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
  private Map<String, Endpoint> endpoints      = new HashMap<>();
  // private Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    endpoints.forEach((key, value) -> {
      List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String role : value.getRoles()) {
        roles.add(ROLE_PREFIX + role);
      }
      value.setRoles(roles.toArray(new String[0]));
    });

    // users.forEach((key, value) -> {
    // if (value.getId() == null) {
    // value.setId(key);
    // }
    //
    // if (value.getEncoding() != null) {
    // value.setPassword("{" + value.getEncoding().trim() + "}" + value.getPassword());
    // } else {
    // value.setPassword("{noop}" + value.getPassword());
    // }
    // });
  }

  public Map<String, Endpoint> getEndpoints() {
    return endpoints;
  }

  public void setEndpoints(Map<String, Endpoint> endpoints) {
    this.endpoints = endpoints;
  }

  // public Map<String, User> getUsers() {
  // return users;
  // }
  //
  // public void setUsers(Map<String, User> users) {
  // this.users = users;
  // }

  public static class Endpoint {
    private String       path;
    private HttpMethod[] methods;
    private String[]     roles;

    // trivial getters/setters removed for brevity

    public String[] getRoles() {
      if (roles == null || roles.length == 0) {
        roles = new String[1];
        roles[0] = ROLE_ANONYMOUS;
      }
      return roles;
    }
  }

  public static class User {
    private String   id;
    private String   encoding;
    private String   password;
    private String[] roles;

    // trivial getters/setters removed for brevity

    public String[] getRoles() {
      if (roles == null || roles.length == 0) {
        roles = new String[1];
        roles[0] = ROLE_ANONYMOUS;
      }
      return roles;
    }
  }
}
```

application.yml:

```
...
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    trust-store-type: JKS
    trust-store: classpath:truststore/server.truststore
    trust-store-password: <password>
    key-store-type: JKS

security:
  auth:
    endpoints:
      endpoint1:
        path: /rst/dummy
        methods: GET
        roles:
```

**CLIENT**

ClientService.java:

```
@Service
public class ClientService {
  private final Logger        logger            = LogManager.getLogger();

  private static final String REST_DUMMY        = "rst/dummy";

  // @Autowired
  // private RestTemplate template;

  @Value("${web.protocol:http}")
  private String              protocol;
  @Value("${mission-planner.host:localhost}")
  private String              missionPlannerHost;
  @Value("${mission-planner.port:8443}")
  private int                 missionPlannerPort;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
  public void planMission() {
    logger.info("ClientService.planMission()");
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    String url = new URLBuilder.Builder().usingProtocol(protocol).onHost(missionPlannerHost)
        .atPort(missionPlannerPort).atEndPoint(REST_DUMMY).build();
    String response = template.getForObject(url, String.class);
  }
}
```

A big question I have is, what (*if any*) "security" configuration needs to be done on the client side, if the server(s) will not need to verify the client? I do have a bunch of classes/config that attempts to do this on the client side, but this is currently disabled.

With the code as shown, I get an exception on the client when I attempt to communicate with the dummy service:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/rst/dummy": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to try changing the `server.ssl.key-alias` (which I set via -D in the run config) to uppercase (which is what the cert appears to have) and now get a new interesting exception. Note: I also set `javax.net.debug=ssl` for both client and dummy service.

```
scheduling-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 196
scheduling-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
scheduling-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
scheduling-1, called closeSocket()
scheduling-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[2019-08-09 13:28:45.648] scheduling-1 ERROR: support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:96 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/rst/dummy": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

This what I get on the service:

```
matching alias: route_assessor_1
matching alias: route_assessor_1
qtp1060563153-39, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
qtp1060563153-39, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
qtp1060563153-39, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
qtp1060563153-39, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
qtp1060563153-39, called closeOutbound()
qtp1060563153-39, closeOutboundInternal()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this was a case of too many moving parts and forgetting to turn something back on.

After quite a bit of flailing about and going back to the original source (https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-tls-example) and experimenting with it for awhile, I couldn't see any significant difference between the author's working code and my non-working code.

Then one of those flash out of the blue situations occurred and I realized that I was **not** using the security configured REST template (it was commented out for reasons I now cannot remember) in my client. I was using just a plain unconfigured template.

I uncommented the code and lo and behold, the client now verifies the server's certificate.

On to the next problem.